# Simple Application to model matrix transformation of basic geometric shapes

Tags: math-software

I've been searching the internet for a simple, free, application that will allow me to experiment with matrix transformations on a 2D and/or 3D graph of geometric shapes.

For example, I'd like to practice creating matrices that can translate, rotate, scale, and shear squares, triangles, and the like to increase my intuition and understanding.

While there are many 3D modelling programs out there, I could not find one that actually allows you to input a matrix and transform the geometric representation.

Does anyone know of software that fits what I am looking for?

Comment: Sounds like a fairly easy thing to write (for the 2D case, anyway).

Comment: Yes I suppose in 2D it wouldn't be too difficult, but I need 3D as well.